# Bridge eth0 and wlan0

Tags: routing, wlan, isc-dhcpd

I've a computer, C, a router R, and a raspberry pi, P. They are connected:

Internet <--ethernet--> R <--wlan--> P <--ethernet--> C

Now I want C to be able to access the internet.

The P has wlan0 and eth0, my first thought was to bridge eth0 and wlan0 but that is not possible due to the nature of wifi I've learned.

Next approach is to add a dhcp server to P and let C lease an IP number. It works fine and `ip route` on C gives:

`10.254.239.0/27 dev eth0  src 10.254.239.13 
default via 10.254.239.10 dev eth0`

and ifconfig on P gives

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:44:bb:71  
          inet addr:10.254.239.10  Bcast:10.254.239.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          inet6 addr: fe80::3206:e7e:fb7e:23d5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:569 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:235 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:142936 (139.5 KiB)  TX bytes:50384 (49.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1444 (1.4 KiB)  TX bytes:1444 (1.4 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:11:ee:24  
          inet addr:192.168.0.106  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2501:6a8:8bcf:4a40/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5415 errors:0 dropped:4989 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:454 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:815495 (796.3 KiB)  TX bytes:49230 (48.0 KiB)
```

C can ping P but not R, leaving me to believe that P has some routing error.

How can I configure P to pass traffic between R and C?

`ip route` on P gives:

```
default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlan0  metric 303 
10.254.239.0/27 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.254.239.10 
192.168.0.0/24 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.106  metric 303
```

Also on P

```
$ cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

Comment: You need to do NAT on the Pi on top of forwarding. Google for tutorials.

Answer (score 4):

That's a classic IP forward case. Run the following command on P:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

Comment: sorry I forgot to write that I've already done that as well (on P)